# Uniqueness of the connecting morphism in the snake lemma

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra, exact-sequence

Consider the following commutative diagram in an abelian category:$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
@. A @>{f}>> B @>{g}>> C @>>> 0\\
@. @VV{a}V @VV{b}V @VV{c}V  \\
0@>>> A' @>>{f'}> B' @>>{g'}> C'
\end{CD}$$

The snake lemma gives a morphism $\delta:\ker c\to \operatorname{coker} a$ making the sequence
$$\ker a \to \ker b\to \ker c\to \operatorname{coker} a \to \operatorname{coker} b \to \operatorname{coker} c$$
exact. I wonder if the morphism $\delta$ is unique **such that the induced sequence above is exact**.

The proof of the snake lemma using elements makes me believe that the answer is yes, but I'm not really sure.

(This is basically the same as [Uniqueness of the connecting homomorphism in theory of abelian categories](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1491307/uniqueness-of-the-connecting-homomorphism-in-theory-of-abelian-categories) but my question adds a condition, so I think that it was worth making a new question. If someone is against this, I can delete my question.)

Comment: Don't think so. Say $A=C'=0$, $B=C\neq 0$, $A'=B'=B\oplus B$, with $g$ and $f'$ the identity functions, and  $b\colon B\to B\oplus B$ is the inclusion into the first component. The sequence you get is $0\to 0\to B\to B\oplus B\to B\to 0$, and all you need is for $\delta$ to map $B$ to $B\oplus 0$ isomorphically. If $B$ has nontrivial automorphisms, you can have lots of $\delta$ that work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order for the sequence to be exact, all you need is an isomorphism between $\def\coker{\operatorname{coker}}\ker c/\operatorname{im}(\ker b\to \ker c)$ and $\ker(\coker a\to\coker b)$. By the snake lemma, these objects *are* isomorphic, but they may well have non-trivial automorpshims that you can sneak into $\delta$.
For abelian groups, you may for example always replace $\delta$ with $-\delta$ (which is the same as $\delta$ only when the quotients in question are of exponent 2). Incidentally, $-\delta$ is also *natural*.